# How to Convert spark dataframe to nested json using spark scala dynamically

Tags: azure, scala, apache-spark, databricks, apache-kafka-streams

I want to convert the  DataFrame to nested json. Sourse Data:-

DataFrame have data value like :-

[image: input]

Expected Output:-

I have to convert DataFrame value to Nested Json like : -

[image: output]

Appreciate your help !

Answer (score 0):

1. If you want to persist the data then save dataframe with format json

```
df.write.json("path")
```

2. You can use toJSON function, which will convert dataframe to Dataset[String]

```
df.toJSON
```

If there's only one element then you can further manipulate to get string

```
df.toJSON.take(1).head
```

Thanks.

Comment: but I want to write the data into nested json. In my case delimiter is . which separate the parent from child. I fast flatten the nested json then I get the data in dataframe after that I want to convert the dataframe into nested json. like same as flatten data before